# Docker compose rolling release without swarm/stack

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, deployment, release

What should I do to achieve sequential update of my containers without using swarm/stack?

I'm using docker-compose.yml file kinda this

```
---
services:
  myservice:
    image: myrepo/myimage:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
```

I've started with docker compose up -d command and can see in docker ps 5 containers running from myimage:latest image.
Then I edit Dockerfile of myimage, build it with tag myrepo/myimage:latest and successfully push to my repo.
Аfter that I'm issuing docker compose pull && docker compose up -d hoping my containers will restart one-by-one with interval of 10 seconds according with this official page:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#update_config
But instead of this all 5 replicas restarting at the same time.

My config:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.14.0
$ cat /etc/*release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
```

Comment: Why do you need a rolling update, and why do you need to implement it with docker compose? I ask because it appears you are attempting to perform production tasks with a developer tool.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why feature described in the official documentation doesn't work.

Comment: For example, docker-compose v. 1.25 can't even implement replicas, v. 1.29 can do this, but when I specified update_config section, it warns me that this section will be ignored.
Docker compose v. 2 doesn't even warn about this ignore so I assumed that in this version update_config is gonna be fine.

Comment: This documentation may help, the deploy section was added for swarm mode, and some of those features have been later ported back to compose, but there's documentation of the spec and documentation of a tool that implements the spec. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy

Comment: The spec describes that the features may not be implemented by all tools that implement the spec: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#requirements-and-optional-attributes

Comment: Thus, should I operate the swarm/stack deploy mode instead of compose to achieve rolling update even though I use the latest version of compose?

Comment: I would recommend that if it wasn't excluded as an option in the question.